# There are values in rows but dataframe returns Nan

Tags: pandas

When i read a dataframe in panda, it returns Nan when there is values in there. Also how do i delete rows where the value is really N/A or blank.

```
# File to read
Exoticoutput=pd.read_excel(Exotic Deltas - SIGN OFF SHEET"+yesterday+".xlsx",sheetname="Exotic deltas (output to Curo)")

Exoticoutput.to_csv(Output\Exotic Deltas"+' '+ yesterday +' '+".csv", columns=["Hiport Code","ISIN","External Code 1","JSE code","Delta"], index=False)# Output file to create.
```

There are values in the Delta column with decimals in the actual excel file, however when i create an output file by reading into a dataframe and exporting gives Nan

First file

Input file 
Option ISIN        Delta

ZADA000            0.60972
ZADA               0.292603

Output file

Option Isin       Delta 
No data           No Data
Nan

The input file has the data but on output file it either reads Nan or blank

is it because the number i am looking for is floating

Sorry for the lack of information, i am new to SE and python programming

Comment: How should we know what the content of the excel file is look like? You should maybe provide a minimal example of the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

hello dear you can use the

> na_values

argument to set the default value for the na cells in addition use

> keep_default_na